# View::composer not working on boot() service provider

Tags: laravel, view, package

Inside a Laravel **Package** `EspacePartenaire` I need to share some data between all its views using **View Composer**.

Ths `boot()` method inside `EspacePartenaireServiceProvider` containes the following:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'espace-partenaire');

View::composer('*', CurrentPartenaireComposer::class);
```

But I don't want to share data in all the views. I need it only in the views that are located in the view folder of the Package `/packages/EspacePartenaire/src/views`

When I change arguments of the composer function like below:

```
View::composer('espace-partenaire', CurrentPartenaireComposer::class);
```

or

```
View::composer('espace-partenaire::*', CurrentPartenaireComposer::class);
```

I had the error that my variables are undefined.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**:
This is the Package routes file:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
    'namespace' => 'App\Services\EspacePartenaire\Http\Controllers',
    'prefix' => 'espace-partenaire'
], function(){
    ...
    Route::get('/', 'EspacePartenaire@index');
    ...
});
```

Comment: View composer is not for routes but for views, how is your view structure?

Comment: It's in a separate folder
`/packages/EspacePartenaire/src/views` and I'm loading them with the `$this->loadViewsFrom()` in PackageServiceProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your packages structure i think the following approach could maybe work, it seems first parameter is the path and you can do * as a wildcard.

```
View::composer('*espace-partenaire*', CurrentPartenaireComposer::class);
```